# Xamarin.Forms (iOS) Requesting tracking Authorization in release will not prompt the user but assume the user clicked denied

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

As of the newest iOS polices, you have the ask the user if you can track him or her. In debug, the below code will open a prompt asking the user wether he or she is ok with being tracked. If given the ok, the app continues, if denied the app ends (after the iMessage).

However, as soon as I put the app into release and deploy it to a real phone, the prompt is always skipped and instead the fail iMessage is shown and the app exits.

Why is the prompt missing on production? In debug, it works totally fine.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    try
    {
        ATTrackingManager.RequestTrackingAuthorization((status) => {
            if (status == ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
            {
                //start once at launch afterwards with timer
                GetNewChatsCount();
                
                SetButtons();
                
                StartChatDownloadCounter();
                
            }
            else if (status == ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().VeryLongAlert("Leider kannst du in diesem Fall die App nicht nutzen. Wir benötigen diese Infos, um allen Kunden ein gesichertes Umfeld zu bieten. Installiere die App neu, wenn du deine Meinung änderst.");
                    await Task.Delay(8000);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I have read on this page: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669490?page=2 that the issue is from iOS side

Comment: How did you import the AttTrackingManager?

Comment: It is standart in newest SDK